# What are the different ways to use ADO Repos? Is there a GUI available?

Tags: git, azure-devops

I'm getting started with Azure Dev Ops, using their Git Repos. I know that one of the advantages of git is that you can have a local repo and work offline.

I'm trying to understand the full scope of ways to use Git in ADO.

From my understanding:

1. Can access ADO Repo via command line
2. Can access ADO Repo via web browser
   etc.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/user-guide/tools?view=azure-devops

Is there any type of GUI also? that's similar to  SourceTree, TortoiseGit. But can these be used/ connected to ADO? I'm trying to find something similar to the listed GUI's or the ADO desktop that can be used offline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can integrate SourceTree with azure devops by adding a remote account.

After downloading SourceTree, perform the following operation:
[image]

If you receive this error message : **Failed to check login for *user*. Insufficient authentication credentials. Sourcetree could not find password for *user* at *DevOps link*** in Credentials. You need to write your Host Url in the old VSTS link format like this : https://OrgName.VisualStudio.com instead of https://dev.azure.com/OrgName .

After successful addition , you will get azure devops repos in SourceTree.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Git support in Azure DevOps is the standard Git protocol. This means that all tools that support Git can connect to Azure DevOps. If your tool supports Azure DevOps authentication (like SourceTree), you don't have to do anything special.

If that's not the case you can use SSH or enable alternate credentials for your repository as discussed in [Authentication overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/auth-overview?view=azure-devops)